# regex question redux regarding definition list

Tags: php, regex

Trying to figure out a way to throw out attributes in this data that do not have any values. Thanks for helping.

My current regex code , thanks to Tomalak looks like this

Regex find

```
([^=|]+)=([^|]+)(?:\||$)
```

Regex replace

```
<dt>$1</dt><dd>$2</dd>
```

Data looks like this

> Bristle Material=|Wire Material=Steel|Dia.=4 in|Grit=|Bristle Diam=|Wire Size=0.0095 in|Arbor Diam=|Arbor Thread - TPI or Pitch=1/2 - 3/8 in|No. of Knots=|Face Width=1/2 in|Face Plate Thickness=7/16 in|Trim Length=7/8 in|Stem Diam=|Speed=6000 rpm [Max]|No. of Rows=|Color=|Hub Material=|Structure=|Tool Shape=|Applications=Cleaning rust, scale and dirt, Light Deburring, Edge Blending, Roughening for adhesion, Finish preparation prior to plating or painting|Applicable Materials=|Type=|Used With=Straight Grinders, Bench/Pedestal Grinders, Right Angle Grinders|Packing Type=|Quantity=1 per pack|Wt.=

End result should like this

```
 <dt>Wire Material</dt><dd>Steel</dd><dt>Dia.</dt><dd>4 in</dd><dt>Wire Size</dt><dd>0.0095 in</dd>
```

Not this

```
 Bristle Material=|<dt>Wire Material</dt><dd>Steel</dd><dt>Dia.</dt><dd>4 in</dd>Grit=|Bristle Diam=|<dt>Wire Size</dt><dd>0.0095 in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in PHP without using regular expressions:

```
$parts_list = explode('|', "Bristle Material=|Wire M....");
$parts      = "";

foreach( $parts_list as $part ){
    $p = explode('=', $part);
    if(!empty($p[1])) $parts .= "<dt>$p[0]</dt>\n<dd>$p[1]</dd>\n";
}

echo $parts;
```

And here is how you can do it with regular expressions:

```
$parts = preg_replace( 
    array('/([^=|]*)=(?:\||$)/','/([^=|]*)=([^|]+)(?:\||$)/'),
    array('', '<dt>$1</dt><dd>$2</dd>'),
    $inputString 
);

echo $parts;
```

**Update**

This is using a special replace feature of the PHP `preg_replace` which takes an array of regex expressions, and an array of replacement strings. The `array()` syntax of the function basically equates to this:

> If I can match this: `/([^=|]*)=(?:\||$)/` then replace it with an empty string.
>   If I can match this: `/([^=|]*)=([^|]+)(?:\||$)/` then replace it with `<dt>$1</dt><dd>$2</dd>`

To test it in a Regex editor, you would run the first expression first (`/([^=|]*)=(?:\||$)/`) then run the second expression on the result of the first expression.

Comment: Tried pasting this into my regex editor. For some reason its not working.

           /([^=|]*)=(?:\||$)/','/([^=|]*)=([^|]+)(?:\||$)/

Comment: Jeff, since you are using PHP (as you mentioned in the other post), just use it in PHP. A simple regex will not do what you want, because you need to *remove* an element without a value, but *replace* elements that do have values. The code I have given you I tested in PHP with your input string and it works. There are two separate regexes in their (using the php `array` to use them both): First: `/([^=|]*)=(?:\||$)/` Second: `/([^=|]*)=([^|]+)(?:\||$)/`

Comment: Jeff, I updated my answer so you could better see what was going on.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am using PHP for the application, but made the assumption that I could just do a simple replacement in a text editor. The source data contains thousands of records in one column of a flat file.

Comment: Jeff, here is a trick that might help you. Setup a php file with a line that has `$inputString = "...pastelargefilehere...";`  and my second solution above. Then from the command line (on a Mac or Linux box this will work, not sure how it works on a PC) run `php -f /path/to/file.php > /path/to/processes.txt` and it will parse the text for you and create a text file with the response.

Comment: Sounds like it may work, but what about the other data in the file. Its a CSV file. I am only trying to change data in one column. Won't it cause issue with the rest of the data?

Comment: Then just copy the one line out for processing, run it through the php file, and paste the results back in place of the original line.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl in the morning. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I took a different approach. I used your php code to change the value on the front end of the site as the product is being displayed instead of transforming the data in the import file. I don't know why I didn't think of this before

Answer (score 0):

```
([^=|]*)=([^|]*)(?:\||$)
```

to skip the ones with out a value, try this:

```
(?:[^=|]*=|([^=|]*)=([^|]+))(?:\||$)
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do it.

Comment: ah, wait, you want to skip the ones that are missing a value?

Comment: You don't want to skip ones without a value, you need to replace them with nothing so they no longer are contained in the string.

Comment: then the second regex should take care of that

Comment: My regex editor is saying that this is not valid:

      (?:[^=|]*=|([^=|]*)=([^|]+))(?:\||$)

Comment: Not sure what the deal is then.

Comment: It is valid, but it is also broken. :) It outputs empty `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements instead of not outputting anything for a key without a value.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want `preg_match` here rather than `preg_replace`

```
 preg_match_all('~([^|]+)=([^|\s][^|]*)~', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
 foreach($matches as $match)
      echo "<dt>{$match[1]}</dt><dd>{$match[2]}</dd>\n";
```